# How does one derive a `BoundedEnum (Maybe a)` from a `BoundedEnum a`?

Tags: purescript

I'm getting an error on "no typeclass instance was found for `Data.Enum.BoundedEnum (Maybe InstitutionContactType)`", but due to the existence of `instance enumMaybe :: BoundedEnum a => Enum (Maybe a)`, `instance boundedMaybe :: Bounded a => Bounded (Maybe a)`, and `instance boundedEnumInstitutionContactType :: BoundedEnum InstitutionContactType`, I would think this should work, though maybe it is because the direction is wrong for what I need in `enumMaybe`?

`boundedMaybe` gives us `Bounded (Maybe a)`, `enumMaybe` gives us `Enum (Maybe a)`, and `class (Bounded a, Enum a) <= BoundedEnum a` should, given  `Bounded (Maybe a)` and `Enum (Maybe a)`, also give us `BoundedEnum (Maybe a)`, and I think I have the directionality correct, which is reversed for instances and classes in terms of what needs to be provided, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I finally realize now this doesn't work, since `BoundedEnum` has three additional members that need to be implemented on top of what is already available in `Bounded` and `Enum`.